# Access a related record with relationship in Blade View

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have 2 tables in a ecommerce website one for products and one for the file names of uploaded images of the products named product_name.
i'm pretty sure i set up the models correctly with my Product model has :

```
public function product_image()
{
    return $this->hasMany(product_image::class);
}
```

And my product_image looks like this :

```
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(product::class);
}
```

In my controller i get the data like so :

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $product -> product_image;
    //dd($product); /* I get the correct data */

    return view('product.show', ['product'=>$product]);
}
```

In my view i can access my product data with `$product -> name` no problem but i can't access the file_name from the relation i've set up.
When i do `dd($product)` in my view i can see my the correct fields are called with the correct data but i can't access the data from my table product_image.
when i do `$product->product_image->file_name` i get :

`Trying to get property 'file_name' of non-object`

Comment: What are your database tables and class names?

Comment: `dd($product->product_image)` is it working ??

Comment: "product" and "product_image" but i don't think the problem is form my DB i think i'm using the wrong synthax to call the product_image in the view

Comment: The result of "dd($product->product_image)" is "NULL"

Comment: what is the name of the foreign key between "product" and "product_image"  tables?

Comment: "product_id" in the "product_image" is the foreign key

Comment: You have to use like this `ProductImage`

Comment: i can change it another time, for now the data is being sent correctly to the view i just dont know the correct synthax and i can't locate the info

Comment: What's your actual model name `product_image`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, class names are PascalCase (every first letter capitalized, no underscores). You haven't posted the "product image" class name, I'm assuming it's `ProductImage`. So you should change the relationships to:

```
public function product_image()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
}
```

and

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

The parameter to those relationship functions is a string of the full class name of the related model, e.g. `App\ProductImage`, which is what `::class` returns.

Then you can use the property directly, Laravel will automatically fetch it from the database, see [Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties):

```
<ul>
  @foreach($product->product_image as $image)
    <li>{{ $image->file_name }}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Even if i change the class name how can i access the data in my view?

Comment: @Evilbleezard I've added an example. If that doesn't work: what does `dd($product->product_image);` output?

Comment: it output "NULL"

Comment: Then the relationship configuration is wrong. Are you sure the property is the same as the relationship method (`product_image`)?

Comment: When i dd($product) i can see the data that i need so the names are correctly set

Answer (score 0):

You have use like this

```
public function product_images(){

    return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
}
```

and model name should be `ProductImage` and use like this `use App\ProductImage`

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the product photos you have to load them first using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::with('product_image')-> findOrFail($id);

   return view('product.show', ['product'=>$product]);
}
```

now $product -> product_image; will give you a collection of product_image

i recommend changing relation name to be plural 'product_images'

Comment: And how should i access it in my view?

Comment: using standard foreach

Comment: it doesn't find the data that's my point i know i can use foreach for an associative array, but i can't access it in the first place

Comment: @foreach($product->product_image as $productImage)
 $productImage->file_name;

Comment: "dd($product->product_image)"  Output "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

I did correct my class names, but the problem was not related with that my relationships was correct but the only was i could display what i needed like this :

```
$produit['ProduitImage'][0]->file_name
```

I don't know why laravel format that way but it did work and i could get my data.
i'm sure there is a better way to do it...